# Silence custom command depending on CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE

Tags: cmake

I've a custom command in my CMake script which generates a lot of output. I'd like to take advantage of CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE so I can decide if I want to see this output or not.

Is there a common way for doing this?

The one way I see is to redirect output to `/dev/null` depending on this CMake's flag, but what about Windows and other OSes?

Is there a portable or recommended way? What about default rules for C/C++ compiling commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically speaking, `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` exists for the purpose of hiding and showing command lines, not command output.

If I had to do this, I would use a custom variable.

But on the main topic, here is how you should do:

```
if (COMMAND_VERBOSE)
  execute_process(COMMAND "mycustom_command")
else (COMMAND_VERBOSE)
  execute_process(COMMAND "mycustom_command" OUTPUT_QUIET)
endif (COMMAND_VERBOSE)
```

This is the most portable way to do so.

There is also an `ERROR_QUIET` flag, however it is a bad idea to disable error messages, else the user would be unable to see why the command failed if it failed.

If you are using `add_custom_command` or `add_custom_target` instead, such a flag does not exist.
You'll have to provide a manual redirection to `/dev/null` (Unix), or `NUL` (Windows).

Answer (score 4):

As SirDarius pointed out, `execute_process()` has an option to silence tool output, while `add_custom_command()` / `add_custom_target()` do not.

But there is a way to work around this: By putting the actual call to your tool in a separate CMake script wrapper, using `execute_process()` with `OUTPUT_QUIET` enabled or disabled depending on a switch:

```
# mycustom_command.cmake
if ( OUTPUT )
    execute_process( COMMAND mycustom_command )
else()
    execute_process( COMMAND mycustom_command OUTPUT_QUIET )
endif()
```

Then, use `add_custom_command()` and the CMake script processing mode (`-P`) to call that script from your main CMakeLists.txt, with the script switch enabled / disabled by whatever variable you use for that purpose in your CMakeLists.txt file.

```
add_custom_command( OUTPUT outfile
                    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P mycustom_command.cmake -DOUTPUT=${OUTPUT_DESIRED}
                  )
```

This is fully portable. If your `mycustom_command` is build from within your project as a target, just add it as `DEPENDENCY` to your `add_custom_command()` to have it build in time for the script call.