# how to escape closing angle bracket symbol in cmake generator expresssions?

Tags: cmake

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
set(BE_QUIET $<$<NOT:$<BOOL:CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE>>:&>/dev/null>)
```

with the aim of using it in `add_cusom_command` like this:

```
add_custom_command(
    ...
    COMMAND ... ${BE_QUIET}
)
```

idea is to suppress custom command output unless user sets CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE (or runs `make VERBOSE=1`).

Problem is that cmake treats that closing angle bracket symbol as end of expression. Is there any way to escape it?

**Edit:** alas, even though I know about `$<ANGLE-R>` now, this idea doesn't work -- you need new expression (smth like `$<CONFIG_FLAGS:VERBOSE>`)

**Edit 2:** found a solution (inject some `make` magic):

```
 set(BE_QUIET "$(if" "$(VERBOSE),,&>/dev/null)")
```

Comment: A cross-platform way of doing this can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31160713/1896169

Comment: You may check `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` variable with simple `if()` command. In CMake, *generator expressions* are NOT replacement for `if` command. Primary purpose of generator expressions is working in situations where `if` *cannot*. E.g., for use values, dependent on build type ("Debug", "Release", etc.), on *multiconfiguration* generators (like Visual Studio). On such generators build type is not known at configuration stage (when `CMakeLists.txt` is processed), so you cannot check build type with simple `if`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev is it possible to build a construct/expression that (depending on current VERBOSE level (which can be selected by means of either `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` or `VERBOSE`)) will resolve to one string or another? I have a feeling that it isn't possible right now -- evaluation has to happen during `make` execution

Comment: No, in CMake code you cannot check `VERBOSE` variable set for `make` invocation. You are right in that CMake code just cannot see that variable. However, I remember that it is possible to use constructions in CMake code, which will be transformed into Makefile as variable's dereference. You may try to use something like `\$(VERBOSE)` for obtain `$(VERBOSE)` in the Makefile. The next step would be to use that dereference to achieve your purpose. E.g., you may write shell script (*wrapper*), which depending on its first parameter executes command line, constructed from other parameters.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried `set(BE_QUIET [=[${VERBOSE:-&>/dev/null}]=])` and `add_custom_command(... COMMAND ... ${BE_QUIET})` but for some unknown reason final cmdline always ends up having empty string where `&>/dev/null` is supposed to be. It looks like there is some additional processing CMak does to cmdline that I am not aware of.

Comment: another thing I noticed is that `$VERBOSE` ends up being `ERBOSE`, i.e. `$V` gets replaced with empty string somewhere %-)

Comment: Looks like `make` itself messes with my expression

Comment: Looks like a bug in CMake -- when it generates related Makefile something doesn't get escaped properly...

Comment: make doesn't like single `$`s in recipe -- it expects it to be escaped by using `$$` instead

Comment: Construction `${VAR}` used in the *shell*, Makefile uses `$(VAR)` construction for this.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Trying to use `set(BE_QUIET "\`if [ -z $$VERBOSE ] $<SEMICOLON> then echo \"&>/dev/null\" $<SEMICOLON> fi\`")` now. It almost works... Unfortunately CMake goes completely nuts when generating makefile recipe -- escaping every space symbol, confusing the hell out of shell.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Trying to deal with this by using `separate_arguments` and converting string to list, but CMake exhibits incomprehensible behavior here... Like stopping space-to-semicolon substitution the moment it hits `$<SEMICOLON>` and etc. Any ideas how to ask CMake to stop being too smart and just do what it is being told to do? :)

Comment: It is known problem that CMake escaping behavior isn't very good. That is why I suggested to prepare wrapper script, which accepts value of `$VERBOSE` and does all other work using normal shell. So no needs in additional escaping of spaces and so.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Omg, I finally made some sense of it out -- at best I end up passing `&>/dev/null` argument to executable :-) Because shell first checks for redirections and only then applies substitutions. So, basically, there are three levels of complexity here -- CMake escaping magic, `make` recipe handing magic (which includes it's own escaping rules) and shell behaviour. No wonder it felt like I am going nuts here. :-) Regarding wrapper script -- I really don't want to maintain a separate file for something trivial like this

Comment: With a good design, a wrapper script may be reused in many parts of the project, or even in the other your projects. But in any case, I am glad that you have won that escaping fight :)

Comment: @Tsyvarev not entirely -- using `BE_QUIET` variable still causes problems (CMake applies weird logic when expanding it in context of `COMMAND` screwing up half of my command after first `$<SEMICOLON>`), I ended up using redirection directly on `COMMAND` itself in divide-and-conquer attempt. Also, I don't think it is possible to implement this "conditional redirection" (at least in it's current form) using additional script at all -- seem to be bash limitation. I think we need `QUIET` option in `add_custom_command` to do it properly...

Comment: @Tsyvarev found a way -- see updated question :)

Comment: Nice. On Stack Overflow we tend to not add solutions to the question post. Could you add your solution as the answer instead?

Comment: well, original question was about escaping `>` symbol, i.e. that solution was kinda for another problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$<ANGLE-R>` (the documentation is under [Output Expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#output-expressions)):

```
set(BE_QUIET $<$<BOOL:CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE>:&$<ANGLE-R>/dev/null>)
```

Note that it's not possible to detect `make VERBOSE=1`, though, as there is no generator expression that tells us whether `VERBOSE=1` was passed.

Comment: Odd... I used `set(BE_QUIET $<$<NOT:$<BOOL:CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE>>:&$<ANGLE-R>/dev/null>)` always resolves to nothing... Regardless if I call `make` with `VERBOSE=1` or not...

Comment: @C.M. What if you use `$<BOOL:${CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE}>`?

Comment: it always resolves to "&>/dev/null". Basically, in this case `${CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE}` gets evaluated during configuration regeneration, not when I run make

Comment: @C.M. Come to think of it, that wouldn't be possible. There is no way to check if `VERBOSE=1` is supplied

Comment: any way to write expression that gets evaluated during `make` run and check `make`-specific variable? (naturally not cross-platform at all)