# cmake and portable nul / /dev/null device

Tags: cmake, portability

In my Cmake script I need to redirect the standard output to the `NUL` / `/dev/null` device. I searched the CMake documentation for a portable solution but didn't find something.

I could do something like

```
if (WIN32)
  set(NULDEV NUL)
else()
  set(NULDEV /dev/null)
endif()
```

and use in the code `${NULDEV}`, but I'd prefer a portable solution coming with CMake.

Edit usage form:

```
add_custom_target(docs
    COMMENT "Generating documentation."
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E chdir ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} "${THE_PROGRAM}" arguments > nul
)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `I need to redirect the standard output to the NUL / /dev/null device` Why? Do you use the NUL or /dev/null device somehow?

Comment: Some processes create some output to stdout that is irrelevant and disturbs the CMake output so redirecting it to `NUL` / `/dev/null` the bit-bucket (I cannot influence this output).

Comment: So you don't want to redirect to /dev/null, you want to ignore stdout. This is XY problem. If you run `execute_process` from your cmake you can grab the output into a variable or a file. Which processes create the output? How do you call them from cmake?

Comment: I just saw the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420822/silence-custom-command-depending-on-cmake-verbose-makefile, I have to study this, hopefully it can bring something, I was hoping that CMake had something build in where one directly could redirect.

Comment: How do are you using `${NULDEV}` in your CMake script? Can you show an example?

Comment: @sergej I added my usage in "pseudo" code.

Comment: It's not an answer, but I simply suggest: don't. You should rather redirect it to some `.log`/`.err` file and leave comment about it if command fails. E.g. (simplified): `COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E chdir ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} "${THE_PROGRAM}" arguments > log.txt 2> err.txt || echo "Something failed, see err.txt" && exit 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running a shell command using `execute_process()` and want to quite the output. you can use the `OUTPUT_QUIET` and/or `ERROR_QUIET` options.

From the [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html?highlight=QUIET) documentation:

> ```
> OUTPUT_QUIET, ERROR_QUIET
>     The standard output or standard error results will be quietly ignored.
> ```

#### Example 1:

```
execute_process(COMMAND "${THE_PROGRAM}" argument OUTPUT_QUIET)
```

---

If you are using `add_custom_target()`, then it is unfortunately not that straight forward. What you could do is:

#### Example 2:

1. Create a wrapper cmake script for executing your program:

   ```
   # generate_docs.cmake
   execute_process(COMMAND "${THE_PROGRAM}" argument OUTPUT_QUIET)
   ```
2. Let CMake execute the wrapper script instead of running the program directly:

   ```
   add_custom_target(docs
       COMMENT "Generating documentation."
       COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P generate_docs.cmake
   )
   ```

Comment: How do you pass project name to wrapper? Or any variable for that matter?